# How to resize and save plots in png format?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot the results from a quantile regression, but am not able to:

1. control the dimensions/size of the plots and
2. save the plots as png.

Here is my code:

```
require(quantreg)
data(engel)
attach(engel)
xx <- income - mean(income)
zz <- c(120, diff(income))
fit1 <- summary(rq(foodexp~xx+zz, tau=2:98/100))
```

Then:

```
png('res.png')
plot(fit1, mfrow=c(1,2))
```

Only the zz plot is saved to the res.png file.. Is there any way I can save the plots in separate files (two and one)? 
and how do I control the width/height of the plots? I like all the individual plots to have width=height (square) when i save them to the .png file?

Comment: Why downvote?  This seems like a reasonable newbie question ...

Comment: I have modified the title to reflect the real question.  This should aid future searching on this topic.

Comment: Perhaps, although it seems to be turning out to be at least as much of a question about manipulating the output of `plot.summary.rqs` as about resizing PNG plots in general ....

Answer (score 33):

You can control the image dimensions by `png` argument.

```
png("image.png", width = 800, height = 600)
plot(...)
dev.off()
```

To "finish" the image, use `dev.off`.

Answer (score 5):

For subdividing the plots:

```
plot(fit1,parm=1:2)
plot(fit1,parm=3)
```

Note that you could have found the answer by careful reading of `?plot.summary.rqs`, but this may not have been obvious: in order to know where to look you would need to do `class(fit1)` to figure out which `plot` method was being used.

Roman's answer takes care of the image dimension stuff.

Comment: thks. Trying to use layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,0), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE)) and then plot(fit1, parm=1), plot(fit1, parm=1), plot(fit1, parm=2) and plot(fit1, parm=3) but i does not work. Also, is there a way to make the last plot 'centered'?

Comment: Your problem is that `plot.summary.rqs` internally uses `par(mfrow=...)` which does not play nicely with `layout`.  What do you want to achieve?  You can get close with `plot(fit1,mfrow=c(2,2))`, but if you want the effect of `layout(mat=matrix(c(1,1,2,2,0,3,3,0),byrow=TRUE,nrow=2)); layout.show(3)` it's going to be harder ...  While I generally like doing as much as possible in R, it may be easier to output the plots separately and then arrange them in whatever your final presentation format is (HTML, Word, LaTeX, whatever ...)