# R square plot side by side

Tags: r, plot

I want to show sevaral plots in square side by side in R, e.g., six plots in `par(mfrow=c(3,2))`. I find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656398/making-square-axes-in-r) that one can make square axes in R by `par(pty="s")` and `asp=1`, then I try

```r
### data
x1 <- 1:6; y1 <- 1:6
x2 <- 1:6; y2 <- 1:6
x3 <- 1:6; y3 <- 1:6
x4 <- 1:6; y4 <- 1:6
x5 <- 1:6; y5 <- 1:6
x6 <- 1:6; y6 <- 1:6

### title
t1 <- 'title1'
t2 <- 'title2'
t3 <- 'title3'
t4 <- 'title4'
t5 <- 'title5'
t6 <- 'title6'

### plot
par(mfrow=c(3, 2))
par(pty="s"); asp=1 # square plotting
plot(x1, y1, pch=16, xlim=c(0, 8), ylim=c(0, 8), asp=asp, ann=F, xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
abline(a=0, b=1)
mtext(side=1, line=2, t1)
plot(x2, y2, pch=16, xlim=c(0, 8), ylim=c(0, 8), asp=asp, ann=F, xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
abline(a=0, b=1)
mtext(side=1, line=2, t2)
plot(x3, y3, pch=16, xlim=c(0, 8), ylim=c(0, 8), asp=asp, ann=F, xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
abline(a=0, b=1)
mtext(side=1, line=2, t3)
plot(x4, y4, pch=16, xlim=c(0, 8), ylim=c(0, 8), asp=asp, ann=F, xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
abline(a=0, b=1)
mtext(side=1, line=2, t4)
plot(x5, y5, pch=16, xlim=c(0, 8), ylim=c(0, 8), asp=asp, ann=F, xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
abline(a=0, b=1)
mtext(side=1, line=2, t5)
plot(x6, y6, pch=16, xlim=c(0, 8), ylim=c(0, 8), asp=asp, ann=F, xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
abline(a=0, b=1)
mtext(side=1, line=2, t6)
```

However, the final entire plot gives large space among the sub-plots. How to show the plots side by side tightly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, the device size just needs to be set rightly. Use a different device such as `png()` or `pdf()` with fixed dimensions and choose them clever.

Also, you may loop over your data instead of repeating code.

```
xlst <- list(1:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:6)
ylst <- list(1:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:6)
tlst <- list("title1", "title2", "title3", "title4", "title5", "title6")

png(filename='plot.png', width=400, height=600)  ## open device

op <- par(mfrow=c(3, 2), pty="s")
lapply(1:6, \(i) {
  plot(xlst[[i]], ylst[[i]], pch=16, xlim=c(0, 8), ylim=c(0, 8), asp=1, ann=F, xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
  abline(a=0, b=1)
  mtext(side=1, line=2, tlst[[i]])
})
par(op)

dev.off()  ## close it
```

[image]

If you use Rstudio you could also try to rescale the "Plots" window with your mouse. However, stuff like legends, axis labels, etc. might get distorted which is why I recommend to use another device.

Comment: Your solution is fantastic! Indeed, I want insert this code in R Markdown using Rstudio. @jay.sf