# Making square axes in R for multiple graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656398/making-square-axes-in-r) shows that one can make square axes in R for one plot. I modify it for multiple graphs as

```r
par(mfrow=c(3,2), pty="s") 
plot(iris[,1], iris[,2], asp=1)
plot(iris[,1], iris[,3], asp=1)
plot(iris[,1], iris[,4], asp=1)
plot(iris[,2], iris[,3], asp=1)
plot(iris[,2], iris[,4], asp=1)
plot(iris[,3], iris[,4], asp=1)
```

However, it produces unnecessary white-space between the columns. How to reduce space gap between them?

I also have tried the `ggplot2` scheme as

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p1 = qplot(iris[,1], iris[,2], asp=1)
p2 = qplot(iris[,1], iris[,3], asp=1)
p3 = qplot(iris[,1], iris[,4], asp=1)
p4 = qplot(iris[,2], iris[,3], asp=1)
p5 = qplot(iris[,2], iris[,4], asp=1)
p6 = qplot(iris[,3], iris[,4], asp=1)
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p5, nrow=3, ncol=2)
```

Although it seems  `ggplot2` is better than `base`, there still exists space between the columns!

My R Markdown toy example is given as follows:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## base 

plotting via base!

```{r multi-squre-plot1, echo=FALSE}
par(mfrow=c(3,2), pty="s") 
plot(iris[,1], iris[,2], asp=1)
plot(iris[,1], iris[,3], asp=1)
plot(iris[,1], iris[,4], asp=1)
plot(iris[,2], iris[,3], asp=1)
plot(iris[,2], iris[,4], asp=1)
plot(iris[,3], iris[,4], asp=1)
```

## ggplot2 

plotting via ggplot2

```{r multi-squre-plot2, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p1 = qplot(iris[,1], iris[,2], asp=1)
p2 = qplot(iris[,1], iris[,3], asp=1)
p3 = qplot(iris[,1], iris[,4], asp=1)
p4 = qplot(iris[,2], iris[,3], asp=1)
p5 = qplot(iris[,2], iris[,4], asp=1)
p6 = qplot(iris[,3], iris[,4], asp=1)
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p5, nrow=3, ncol=2)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

In `base` you can use `mar` and `oma` like this:

```r
par(mfrow=c(3,2), pty="s", mar = c(1, 1, 1, 1), oma = c(1, 1, 1, 1)) 
plot(iris[,1], iris[,2], asp=1)
plot(iris[,1], iris[,3], asp=1)
plot(iris[,1], iris[,4], asp=1)
plot(iris[,2], iris[,3], asp=1)
plot(iris[,2], iris[,4], asp=1)
plot(iris[,3], iris[,4], asp=1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You can check the specification by running `?par`.

Comment: Tks for replying, while your way is nearly the same as the `ggplot2` solution, and  the gap between the columns is still too large.  Besides, your way misses (or suppresses) the `xlab` as well. @Quinten