# R: plotting decision tree labels leaves text cut off

Tags: r, plot, rpart

(I'm still learning how to handle images in R; this is sort of a continuation of [rpart package: Save Decision Tree to PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424691/rpart-package-save-decision-tree-to-png?noredirect=1#comment23552980_16424691) )

I'm trying to save a decision tree plot from rpart in PNG form, instead of the provided postscript. My code looks like this:

```
png("tree.png", width=1000, height=800, antialias="cleartype")
plot(fit, uniform=TRUE, 
   main="Classification Tree")
text(fit, use.n=TRUE, all=TRUE, cex=.8)
dev.off()
```

but cuts off a little of the labels for the edge nodes on both sides. this isn't a problem in the original `post` image, which I've converted to png just to check. I've tried using both `oma` and `mar` settings in `par`, which were recommended as solutions for label/text problems, and both added white space around the image but don't show anymore of the labels. Is there any way to get the text to fit?

Comment: Try reading the documentation contained at `?plot.rpart` and pay particular attention to the `margin` argument.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know there were quite so many ways to set margins. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

The `rpart.plot` package plots rpart trees and automatically takes care of
the margin and related issues.  Use `rpart.plot` (instead of `plot` and `text` in the `rpart` package).  For example:

```
library(rpart.plot)
data(ptitanic)
fit <- rpart(survived~., data=ptitanic)
png("tree.png", width=1000, height=800, antialias="cleartype")
rpart.plot(fit, main="Classification Tree")
dev.off()
```

Comment: This.  Margins are not the only problem.  Sometimes plot cuts off text labels arbitrarily.

Answer (score 15):

The default margin is 0. So if your text is a set of words or just a long word, try to put more margin in plot call. For example,

```
plot(fit, uniform=TRUE,margin=0.2)
text(fit, use.n=TRUE, all=TRUE, cex=.8)
```

Alternatively, you can adjust text font size by changing cex in text call. For example,

```
plot(fit, uniform=TRUE)
text(fit,use.n=TRUE, all=TRUE, cex=.7)
```

Of course, you can adjust both mar in plot call and cex in text call to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

On rpart man, at `rpart()` examples the author gives the solution, set par options with `xpd = NA`:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2), xpd = NA)
```

otherwise on some devices the text is clipped

Answer (score 0):

Problem tiwh titanic dataset is rplot will not join ages and fare to display a nive "age > 10" label. It will display them by extension, like:

> age = 11,18,19,22,24,28,29,30,32,33,37,39,40,42,45.5,5,56,58,60...

That makes no room for labels (see the picture)

[bad labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CpQY.png)

Solution is here:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/rpart-result-is-too-small-to-see/60702/4

Basically, you have to mutate age and fare columns into numeric variables. Like:

```
clean_titanic <- titanic %>% 
  select(-c(home.dest, cabin, name, x, ticket)) %>%
  mutate(
    pclass = factor(pclass, levels = c(1, 2, 3), labels = c('Upper', 'Middle', 'Lower')),
    survived = factor(survived, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c('No', 'Yes')),
    # HERE. Also notice I'm removing dots from numbers
    age = as.numeric(age),
    fare = as.numeric(fare)
  )
```

That will give you better labels, and room for them in the plot.

One more thing: you could get a warning when you force non numeric values with as.numeric, and there are a couple of ways to solve that, like replacing characters or ignoring the warning. Ignore like:

```
suppressWarnings(as.numeric(age)))
```

[good plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5rfn.png)